# How to check whether an UI element exists without failing Xamarin Test Cloud?

Tags: xamarin, testing, popup, xamarin-test-cloud

I am using Visual Studio C# with Xamarin to develop an iOS app. I have an UI automation which runs in Xamarin Test Cloud.

I want to check if a pop up window exists, and if it exists I want to dismiss it, othervise test should just continue. The code I am using in the test method is like below:

```
try
{
    app.WaitForElement(x => x.Text("Update available"));
    app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Ignore"));
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    // TODO: This catch doesn't work. Test in cloud still fails.
}
```

The problem is that the catch doesn't work. When the test runs in Xamarin Test Cloud, the test still fails with time out error finding the element.

Does anyone know how to do it without failing the test?

Comment: The default is 1 minute in test cloud, so if it takes longer than that. There's an issue on your end. You may want to look into why it's taking over a minute to have an element appear.

Comment: did you figure out why the catch block is never called ? I'm facing the same problem, the exception goes directly to runtime and test fails, and this is only when running in the cloud :(

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this one but it is 2019 and I can't find a way to make app.WaitForElement to work.

When the element is not found after the timeout, it generates a (documented) System.TimeoutException which is surprisingly not caught by the code above.

Haven't re-checked on Xamarin Test Cloud, but even locally does the problem occur.

Now, the marked solution can't be right. App.Query will return immediately while the purpose of WaitForElement is clearly to allow waiting for a certain amount of time for the said element to appear.

Did anyone have make this work yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `app.Query` method to check if the element exist if you want to avoid using the `WaitForElement`

The `app.Query` returns array of elements for the query

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I came across this recently.

I just wrote a quick helper method that does the same thing but doesn't throw an exception -

```cs
private static void SafeWaitForElement(this IApp app, Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> query, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
{
    timeout = timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (time.Elapsed < timeout)
    {
        var result = app.Query(query);

        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

---

The reason I needed this was because I had some test randomly fail on devices because of the loaders.

Some runs would complete `WaitForNoElement` before the loader even appeared making the tests fail as it then moves on to other actions. The following now waits for the loader to appear/ or continues to the `WaitForNoElement` after 250 ms

```cs
public static void NoLoader(IApp app)
{
    app.SafeWaitForElement(x => x.Class("ProgressBar"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

    // Wait till no loading
    app.WaitForNoElement(x => x.Class("ProgressBar"));
}
```